# attribute value of current object changes when doing some operation on another object

Tags: java, oop, junit

I'm working on some simple java program, and I face this problem : 
I've a card class representing an account number, I am trying to get all alternative account numbers with the method : getValidCards given **numbers** (which has 9 numbers)

the method : getAlternativeNumbers is a method from Number class which calculates single alternative numbers.
in my class test I call

```
Assert.assertEquals(cardToTest.getValidCards(),"899999999");
```

Class Card :

```
private List<Number> numbers;

public String getValidCards(){
    List<Card> toReturn = new ArrayList<>();
    Card accountNumber;
    for(int index=0 ; index < 9 ; index ++){
        accountNumber = new Card(numbers);
        List<number> alternatives = accountNumber.numbers.get(index).getAlternativeNumbers();
        for(int j=0 ; j < alternatives.size(); j++){
            accountNumber.replace(index, alternatives.get(j));
            if(accountNumber.isValid()){
                toReturn.add(accountNumber);
            }
        }
    }
    return printFinalListOfNumbers(toReturn);
}
```

my problem is : the replace method  :

```
private void replace(int index ,Number number){
    numbers.set(index,number);
}
```

This is operating on the attribute **numbers** changing it, and when I initialize *accountNumber = new Card(numbers);* it is taking the numbers that have been changed, but I was changing the numbers of object AccountNumber not the numbers from the object from which I make the call in my test : card.getValidDigits();

if anyone knows the answer please help..

Comment: You have a single mutable `numbers` list shared by several `Card` objects. If you modify it like you're doing, of course the numbers change.

Comment: the numbers is not really shared, when i create a new object with numbers as parameter, it's as if i create a new numbers which is not shared, it' not the same numbers for Card isn't it ??

Comment: Of course not. You don't magically create new objects just by passing parameters. It's just the reference to the original single list being passed, so all your `Card` objects are sharing the same `numbers`.

Comment: Clearly it *is* shared. If you think otherwise, provide the code that you think implements the non-sharing semantics.

Comment: okay, i understand, the reference to numbers thing, i didn't think it will operate like this,  what do you think is the solution for me to make the new Card object reference another numbers atribute to change it without impacting the original one ?

Comment: Show the code, get an answer. Don't show the code, ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make the `Card` constructor copy the passed in parameter, for example

```
public Card(List<Number> numbers) {
    this.numbers = new ArrayList<>(numbers);
}
```

this way the internal `numbers` will be a separate copy with the same contents as they were during creation.